# Json decode in javascript

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have encoded my required data in the json object ,but i want to decode the json object into a javscript array, my json encoded object is :

```
{"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"65"}
```

however i want to use this json in my java script and want it to be available to a java script array

so if i do :

```
var arr = new Array()
arr = <?php json_decode('$json_object',TRUE); ?>;
```

however when i check my page source i get null i.e  arr = 
how can i assign my json object converted to array to java script array ?
further how to access the json objects from java script array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`json_decode` returns a PHP data structure. If you want to serialise that to a JavaScript data structure you have to pass it through `json_encode` (and then actually `echo` the string that it returns).

Note that `json_encode` outputs a JavaScript data structure that is safe for injecting into a `<script>` element in an HTML document. Not all JSON is safe to do that with (PHP adds additional escape sequences, and will transform plain strings, numbers, null values, etc (which aren't legal JSON on their own).

Note that there is also no point in creating a new array and assigning it to `arr` if you are going to immediately assign something else to `arr`.

Also note that `'$json_object'` will give you a string starting with the `$` character and then the name of the variable. Single quoted string in PHP are not interpolated.

```
var arr;
arr = <?php echo json_encode(json_decode($json_object,TRUE)); ?>;
```

Also note that this JSON:

```
{"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"65"}
```

Will transform in to a PHP *associative* array or a JavaScript *object* (which is **not** an array).

So given this PHP:

```
<?php
    $json_object = '{"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"65"}';
?>
<script>
    var arr;
    arr = <?php echo json_encode(json_decode($json_object,TRUE)); ?>;
    alert(arr.product_id);
</script>
```

You get this output:

```
<script>
    var arr;
    arr = {"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"65"};
    alert(arr.product_id);
</script>
```

Which alerts *62* when run.

Comment: ok , even if i just directly assign arr = <?php echo $json_object?> i cant seem to be able to access the array

Comment: Quentin i tried that , but still in the page source , i get arr as null

Comment: Won't `echo json_encode(json_decode($json_object,TRUE));` be identical to `echo $json_object;`?

Comment: @DaveRandom — For the specific input in the example it will. Note my comments (paragraph 2 of the answer) about PHP adding additional escapes. If the input was `{"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"</script>"}` then the output would be `{"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"<\/script>"}`. If you put the former chunk of JSON directly into a `<script>` element, it would terminate the script mid-expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the JSON objects into javascript array and iterate through the array, selecting the appropriate fields you need.
Fixed it..

```
    var json = {"product_id":"62","product_quantity":"65"}; 
    var array = new Array();
    array.push(json);   
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       console.log(array[i].product_id)
    }
```

Comment: Why does everyone always asume everyone uses jQuery! please edit to an for in loop ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay so to start off :

the json string generated in PHP can be used in Javascript as an Object. If you declare the variable as an array to start with then it might conflict.

anyway this should work :

```
<?php 
$error_fields_structure = array(
     'product_id' => 4531
    ,'main_product_quantity' => 2
);

$json_object = json_encode($error_fields_structure);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var jsonstring = <?php echo (isset($json_object) ? $json_object : 'nothing here'); ?>

            for( var i in jsonstring ){
                alert( i +' == ' +jsonstring[i] );
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```